# HTML Table Overflows Footer

Tags: css, html, overflow

**What this problem is NOT**

I do not have the very common problem of the footer not sticking to the bottom of the page. The footer *does* stick to the bottom of the page, and that's fine.

**What the problem *is*:**

When I have more records in my table than the height of the browser window, the table's height overflows the footer. The footer appears sticking to the bottom of the page/window but just a few rows above the table's last row.

It looks like this:

[image]

I am using HTML 5 with ASP.NET MVC and this happens in all browsers.

I have the following HTML structure:

```html
<div id = "header">...</div>

<div id = "parent">
  <form id = "frm">
    <div id = "gridContainer">
      <table id = "theStringsGrid">
        ....
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class = "push" ></div>
</div>

<div id = "footer">...</div>
```

And the following CSS (only the relevant parts are given below):

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; font-family: Sans-Serif; font-size: small; }

#parent { min-height: 100%; position: relative; margin: 0 20px -4em; }

.push { clear: both; }

#footer { height: -4em; clear: both; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; }

#theStringsGrid 
{ 
    table-layout: fixed;

    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right:20px;

    border-width: 2px; 
    border-color: Gray; 
    border-style: groove; 

    font-family: Century Gothic, Calibri, Batang, Verdana, Arial;

    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;

    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 1200px;
}

#theStringsGrid tr { line-height: 9px; }

#theStringsGrid tr td 
{ 
    border-style: groove; 
    border-width: 0px; 
    border-color: Gray; 
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px; 

    height: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**UPDATE: FIXED**

Thank you all for the time you spent on my problem. All your comments and answers were really helpful in enabling me to track down the problem.

But my light-bulb went on because of @JamesDonnelly's comment to the question that reads, "*Why does your footer have `-4em` height?*".

I changed the `height` of the `footer` from `-4em` to `4em` and the `bottom` `margin` of `#parent` also from `-4em` to `4em` and the thing now looks nice like this:

[image]

Here are the changes I made:

```
#parent { min-height: 100%; position: relative; margin: 0 20px 4em; }

#footer { height: 4em; clear: both; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; }
```

Comment: Can you drop it into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?? Please?

Comment: Sure. Let me try. I've never done it before, though. I might take some time. But I'll do it.

Comment: Why does your footer have `-4em` height?

Comment: And you want your footer where? botom of the page or the browsers size?

Comment: That can't be all the relevant CSS. Your footer has `position:fixed` set somewhere, but that's not visible in the CSS you posted.

Comment: @user1618143 it's not positioned fixed.

Comment: Nice Question Presenations

Comment: @Danko: If it doesn't have `position:fixed`, then how is it sticking to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Thank you. Your comment made me think and helped me resolve the issue.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly If you want to add that as an answer, I'm happy to mark it as the correct one. It'll help someone else in the future.

Comment: @user1618143 it's sticking based on the #parent height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to remove the `-` from your `footer`'s height:

```css
#footer { height: 4em; ... }
```

Comment: Good job... You have seen it! +1

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the best idea will be to set a `max-height` to the parent element of the `#theStringsGrid` table...

```css
#gridContainer {
     max-height : 1000px;/*for example*/
     overflow-y: auto; /* scroll only if needed*/
}
```

And to set correctly the `max-height` of the table, use some jQuery :

```
var refreshMaxHeight = function() {
   //try it but document should be better
   var windowsHeight= $( window ).height(); // returns height of browser viewport
   var windowsHeight= $( document ).height(); // returns height of HTML document
   $('#gridContainer').css({'max-height' :
         windowsHeight
         -$('#footer').height()
         -$('#gridContainer').position().top
    });
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    refreshMaxHeight();
    //manage the resize event could be a good idea
    $( window ).resize(function() { refreshMaxHeight();});

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Joe. I tried your solution as well, but the problem persisted. Although your solution helped me introduce auto-scrolling, it wasn't what I was looking for. Also, it did not address the main issue. However, you were immensely helpful as you came up with a lot of good thoughts even without me making the JSFiddle and I could see from your numerous edits that you spent a lot of time on my problem. So, thank you very, very much. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you leave position fixed on your table it will always goes over the footer.

3 solutions:

1. use position relative on the table but it depends on what you need
2. use z-index on footer so it stays up to the overflow
3. set max height to your table and allow overflow inside it so you can scroll.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Stefano. Your answer helped me think. I don't think I needed auto-scroll, though, but you did help me as I will try out your suggestions for future pages I develop.